# Users not showing at login screen with MacOS FileVault Enabled

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, filevault

After adding a new user, it seems that the user does not show at the login screen.

This issue came up after FileVault was enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a new user, that you added on your Mac, does not show at the login screen and you have FileVault enabled on your Mac, then the user(s) are probably not enabled in FileVault. This means that they do not have the authority to decrypt the data you have encrypted using FileVault.

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.1

**Enabling User in File Vault:**

1. Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy

[image]

2. Click on the lock icon on the bottom left corner of the window and enter your password
3. Click on the FileVault tab and then click on the Enable users... button

[image]

You should then be given the opportunity to enable the additional account(s) by providing the account's password.

After a restart, the new account(s) should now appear at the login screen.

**If the accounts are still not visible at the login screen:**

Sometimes this may happen, even after all the steps you have taken above.

The quickest and easiest way that fixes is this is opening up terminal and executing this following command:

```
sudo diskutil apfs updatePreboot /
```

Reboot and all your users should be showing. This may even solve the problem automatically when you add further users. Cheers!

Comment: Confirming, this is still valid for Big Sur 11.6 :)